# How to monkey patch the "python --version" command?

Tags: python, pip, command-line-interface, setuptools, monkeypatching

The `-v`/`--version` flag is used to print out the version of the respective `python` interpreter.

For example, if `python` is aliased to the Python 3.7.9 interpreter, the flag would print out the following:

```
$ python --version
Python3.7.9
```

Can one create a Python module which on installation monkey patches this command for the user? Caveat is that this needs to be cross-platform. How would one about doing so?

For example, say I have `my-package` uploaded on PyPI. If I installed it, it would modify the behaviour of `pyhton -v`/`python --version`.

```
$ python --version
Python3.7.9
$ pip install my-package
...
$ python --version
<some custom text>
```

Preferably on uninstallation, the `-v`/`--version` goes back to normal.

Comment: why do you need this function?

Comment: enter Austin Power "I also like to live dangerously" GIF

Comment: @Andy_ye Had an idea to use some [ASCII art I made](https://ascii.matthewbarber.io/art/python/) along with FIGlet fonts to spruce up the output lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can review the code that parses the command-line arguments (in this example , for CPython) which is on [`initconfig.c` line 1900](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8f42748ded5e978fe8a924115179d45a74a6363b/Python/initconfig.c#L1901).

If the `--version` or `-V` flags are provided then `print_version` becomes non-zero which triggers the condition on [line 2051](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8f42748ded5e978fe8a924115179d45a74a6363b/Python/initconfig.c#L2051):

```
if (print_version) {
    printf("Python %s\n",
            (print_version >= 2) ? Py_GetVersion() : PY_VERSION);
    return _PyStatus_EXIT(0);
}
```

So, the said module would need to somehow modify the value of `PY_VERSION` or the output of `Py_GetVersion()`.

Changing `PY_VERSION` is impossible since it is [hard-coded in `patchlevel.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4fe098d1ee4f4056ac65cae55f5ffdd439dede0/Include/patchlevel.h#L26).

Modifying the output of `Py_GetVersion()` is also impossible [since it uses `PY_VERSION`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Python/getversion.c#L13).

So it appears that the answer is no, this is not possible without recompiling the entire interpreter.

Comment: That was a great, concise explanation—much appreciated thanks :)